# Magento step by step selecting color,size, and grouped products

Tags: magento

How I can make my magento product page look like this?
http://www.thewhitecompany.com/home/furniture/beds/cavendish-headboard/

With selecting color,size, and then products quantity.

Comment: You need extension for it http://www.mageworx.com/advanced-product-options-magento-extension.html but still you have to tweak this extension too. i have done it before :P

Answer (score 0):

This can be done through configurable products.

Step 1- Create different products for each size and color.

Step 2- Create one configurable product, and associate the above created products into it.

Here is tutoral how to create configurable product.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-a-configurable-product

Just posted the same answer to your previous question. This is the simple and best way to do this.